# Is there a specialization to carry more grenades for the M320?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there a way to carry more grenades for the M320? I have the AMMO and EXP specializations but I haven't noticed them increasing my carry capacity for grenades.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Explosives specialization is supposed to, if it's not then it's a bug.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but I only carry one in the tube and three extra. I have in one situation seen one in the tube and *four* extra but can't remember how I got it, and whether or not I could have more than four. Have googled around with not much joy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FRAG perk, achieved at rank 20, has this description:

> Additional MOLLE grenade pouches allow the soldier to carry a **larger amount of hand grenades and 40mm grenades.**

When you equip the frag perk:

- You get 1 more grenade, going from 1 to 2.
- I *believe* you only get 1 more 40mm grenade, going from 4 total (1/3) to 5 total (1/4)

Comment: Ok cool. I'm rank 18 atm. So I wonder how I got 1/4 in the past. Maybe it was a bug.

Comment: Actually I might have got SQD FRAG, rather than bug. That would explain why I've been so confused :-|